# Wrong result of std::fpclassify for long double using Valgrind

Tags: c++, gcc, valgrind

I bump into with strange behaviour. In this program I try check is floating point value equals to zero:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
    float       fa (0), fb (0);
    double      da (0), db (0);
    long double la (0), lb (0);

    cout << "Float:       " << (FP_ZERO == fpclassify (fa - fb) ) << endl;
    cout << "Double:      " << (FP_ZERO == fpclassify (da - db) ) << endl;
    cout << "Long double: " << (FP_ZERO == fpclassify (la - lb) ) << endl;
    cout << "Float:       " << (FP_ZERO == fpclassify (fa - 42) ) << endl;
    cout << "Double:      " << (FP_ZERO == fpclassify (da - 42) ) << endl;
    cout << "Long double: " << (FP_ZERO == fpclassify (la - 42) ) << endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The result of the program is predictable:

```
$ ./llvlg 
Float:       1
Double:      1
Long double: 1
Float:       0
Double:      0
Long double: 0
```

But if I launch the program via Valgrind the result will be wrong for long double zero:

```
$ valgrind ./llvlg 
==7521== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==7521== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==7521== Using Valgrind-3.12.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==7521== Command: ./llvlg
==7521== 
Float:       1
Double:      1
Long double: 0
Float:       0
Double:      0
Long double: 0
==7521== 
==7521== HEAP SUMMARY:
==7521==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7521==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 73,728 bytes allocated
==7521== 
==7521== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==7521== 
==7521== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==7521== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Is it a bug or expected behaviour?

**UPD**:
Source code of the program available [here](https://gitlab.com/Gluttton/SOS/tree/master/44316523).
Build options: `g++ main.cpp -O0 -o llvlg`.
My environment:

- `$ uname -a
  Linux tiptop 4.8.0-53-generic #56-Ubuntu SMP Tue May 16 00:23:44 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
- `$ gcc --version
  gcc (Ubuntu 6.2.0-5ubuntu12) 6.2.0 20161005`
- `$ valgrind --version
  valgrind-3.12.0.SVN`
- `$ cat /proc/cpuinfo 
  ...
  model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4700MQ CPU @ 2.40GHz
  ...`

Comment: Just tested on Valgrind-3.12.0 (x86_64) and the result is exactly the same.

Comment: Perhaps related to a bug I have seen with boost: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/10005. Apparently valgrind is not able to directly claim, initialise or write memory for long doubles.

Comment: @syntagma, `exactly the same` - do you mean, that ptoblem not reproduced?

Comment: Yes, output of running program via Valgrind and directly is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour with Valgrind - a known limitation. Internally long double is only represented with 64bit (double) precision.

See [here](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/valgrind/valgrind_27.html).